# Finding the component value of PNP transistor

Tags: transistors, pnp

This is my circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxbfBI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the way I tackled this problem:

$$ U_{e2} = 12 - I_e \cdot R_e  = 12 - (2.02 \cdot 2) = 7.96 \text{  V} $$

$$ I_e = \left( 1 + \beta \right)  \left( \frac{ I_C }{ \beta } \right) =  \left( 1 + 100 \right)  \left( \frac{ 2 \text{ mA} }{ 100 } \right) = 2.02 \text{ mA} $$

This is where I'm struggling:
$$ I_{be} = I_e - I_c = (2.02-2) \text{ mA} \rightarrow 0.02 \text{ mA} $$

I don't know how to find \$U_{be}\$ so I can find the resistance of \$R_{be}\$

I have been trying to find a tutorial and some help from  several articles.

Comment: What problem???

Comment: @Andy aka, finding Ube so I have then find Rbe

Comment: Why on earth did you write the question _as an image_? It's not searchable.

Comment: @pipe  I have done it in word becuase I dont know how to paste equations here. sorry

Comment: Ube=0.60V @Ic=1mA so use that

Comment: Ue2 is ~8V so the resistor value is not very dependent on the value of Vbe. If you use 0.6V or 0.7V it will make little difference.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, let say it is a transistor that has Ube=0,3v. Would Rbe= 0,3/0.02ma ?

Comment: What is the voltage across Rbe?

Comment: @be1995 I like your approach to show a decent formulated, readable question. +1 for that.  I converted your image to text in order to make it searchable on the site. If you don't find any errors and agree with this update, please delete the image by deleting ```[![enter image description here][1]][1]``` in your original question.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany  in the case scenario that  Ube = 0.3 than I would say Rbe= 0,3/0.02ma ?

Comment: @Huisman thank you. I have deleted the photo

Comment: What is the voltage across Rbe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration is very unstable with only 1 pull-up resistor for bias.

You can never predict Ve using assumptions of hFE due to the wide hFE tolerance and total dependence of hFE on bias voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8k67r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Vbe will be around to 0.65V ± 0.05 @ 2mA, if you look up many datasheets shown as typical values in the curves section @ 25'C, so it can be neglected as the uncertainty is dominated by hFE tolerance error.

[image: All silicon transistors]

Checking from a simulation.
If hFE=100 Vbe=613mV Vcc=12V, Ie=2mA, Re=2k, **Rb=370k**
Using formula Schematic above: Vcc-Ve = 4V = **2k/(2k+Rb/100)*12V**
For Rb=370k, Vcc-Ve= 2k/(2k+3.7k)*12V = **4.2V .. close enough**
but if we apply tolerance error **hFE=150** Ve= 2k/(2k+2.47k)*12V= **5.36V**  ... wide tolerance error.
For details on  Vbe vs Ic
[Vbe vs Ic characteristics of NPN transistor at different Vce in active region](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337242/vbe-vs-ic-characteristics-of-npn-transistor-at-different-vce-in-active-region)

Comment: The teacher usually buys thousands of transistors and tests each one hoping to find one with Vbe= 0.7V and a beta of 100.

Answer (score 1):

Vbe is a range of voltages depending on the transistor type, its current and on its part number. A transistor type is germanium (Vbe= 0.2V - 0.4V) or silicon (Vbe= 0.6V - 0.75V).
Your circuit has a transistor with no part number so you cannot lookup its range of Vbe.

You assumed a beta of 100 which is wrong because it is also a range that could be from 20 to 600. Its datasheet would show its range of beta.

Comment: in this case beta is 100 and   lets say the transistor is 0.7V

Comment: I like the superbeta transistors with hFE > 2000